# Attachment not opening on sending email via Powerautomate

Tags: error-handling, email-attachments, power-automate

I am using powerautomate to send out emails with brochures as attachment. I have tried using onedrive, sharepoint, and google drive and the file size is in the limit (11 MB). However on sending the email, the brochure is not opening and it shows an error on opening the attachment.
I am attaching a screenshot of the same.

[image]

Tried it using onedrive, sharepoint and google drive but nothing seems to be working

Comment: Update your question with a snip of your flow, especially with how you are composing the email with attachment.